Why is an Array.map() necessary, otherwise the var is undefined? / How to eliminate the Array.map()?
I have some JavaScript code running in node.js which controls puppeteer to automate tasks in a web browser.
This code gets a list of links on the page and outputs them to the console:
const links = await page.evaluate(() => { return [...document.querySelectorAll('a')].map(({href, innerText}) => ({href, innerText})); });
links.forEach(a => console.log(`<a href="${a.href}">${a.innerText.trim()}</a>`));

If I remove the map() like this:
const links = await page.evaluate(() => { return [...document.querySelectorAll('a')]; });
links.forEach(a => console.log(`<a href="${a.href}">${a.innerText.trim()}</a>`));

Then I get this error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'trim')

Is there any way to work directly on the original array, without having to make a copy of the array using map()?
There are a couple of hundred properties on each <a> link, which I'd have to type out one at a time in the map() if I wanted to use many of them.

As an aside, is there any way to combine the 2 lines of code in to 1?
If I change it to this:
await page.evaluate(() => { return [...document.querySelectorAll('a')].map(({href, innerText}) => ({href, innerText})); })
    .forEach(a => console.log(`<a href="${a.href}">${a.innerText.trim()}</a>`));

Then I get this error:
TypeError: page.evaluate(...).forEach is not a function

I also found that it doesn't seem to be possible to do a console.log() whilst inside a page.evaluate() (I get no output). This is why I moved the forEach on to a 2nd line.

I can't think of a reason why you need the map().

You also don't need to convert the result to an array with [...], since the collection returned by querySelectorAll() has a forEach() method.

You can combine the two lines using .then(): page.evaluate(...).then(links => links.forEach(...))

@Barmar If I remove the [...] spread operator then I get TypeError: document.querySelectorAll(...).map is not a function

I said it supports forEach(), not map(). I was talking about the version without map().

@Barmar It doesn't appear to be possible to do a console.log() whilst inside a page.evaluate(). If I remove the map() then it's undefined

In the version without map(), what do you see if you do console.log(links)

Where are you looking for the console output? Inside page.evaluate() I think it will be in the browser's console, not the node.js console.

@Barmar For the version without map() when I do console.log(links) I get this: [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}] - one {} for each link found

@Barmar I think you're correct regarding the browser's console vs Node's console :)

I think this is something specific to puppeteer and how it returns data to the client. Unfortunately I don't know much about puppeteer.

@Barmar No problem, thanks for trying - I really appreciate it! I'll retag the question now... beat me to it ;)

IT goldman has correctly identified why trying to return an array of Nodes won't work--HTML elements aren't serializable.
It's possible to remove the map and operate on the original objects, but it will result in worse code. Mutating the original array of nodes to make them serializable isn't a good idea since it's risk to modify objects you don't own.
Avoid premature optimization. It's OK to copy by default and only switch to in-place modification once you encounter a bottleneck and have profiled and determined that in-place modification really does account for the performance issue--highly unlikely.
As far as the Puppeteer API goes, you can immediately simplify
await page.evaluate(() =>
  [...document.querySelectorAll("a")].map(...)
);

to
await page.$$eval("a", els => els.map(...));

The parameter els passed to the callback is a regular array, so .map is available without a spread.

I also found that it doesn't seem to be possible to do a console.log() whilst inside a page.evaluate() (I get no output). This is why I moved the forEach on to a 2nd line.

By default, the browser console output goes to your browser, not Node, because that's the environment the evaluate callback runs in.
You can forward the browser console to Node, but whether that's appropriate or not is unclear. You haven't provided much context for what you're doing here, or why you're mapping links back to formatted links with stripped attributes (you might want to use .outerHTML instead, depending on what you're actually trying to achieve).
I'd avoid smushing multiple lines onto one. Let two lines be two lines (or more)--just write clear code and use an autoformatter. await is not amenable to chaining or one-liners (by design!), so I'd avoid the (await foo()).property antipattern in favor of two lines.
Consider
const links = await page.$$eval("a", els =>
  els.map(a => `<a href="${a.href}">${a.textContent.trim()}</a>`)
);
links.forEach(console.log);

or
const links = await page.$$eval("a", els => els.map(el => el.outerHTML));
links.forEach(console.log);

Generally, prefer .textContent to .innerText.
Note also that it's possible for a links to not have hrefs, so you might want to adjust your selector to a[href].

What does "Mutating the original array of nodes isn't a good idea. Don't modify objects you don't own, and avoid premature optimization." refer to? I approve everything in your answer but that paragraph.

Theoretically, one could loop over the original array of nodes returned by querySelectorAll, prune out the circular references in the HTML elements and return that serializable structure back to Node. This would technically avoid the map. But it's not a good idea for obvious reasons. As for premature optimization, I assumed that was part of OP's motivation for avoiding the map (copying/doing two loops over the data and allocating new objects).

Ah, I get it now, thanks for the clarification

Thank you for such a detailed answer, this really helped!

The map is necessary to convert each HTMLElement into a serializable object { href, innerText } that can be passed in page.evaluate from the context of the browser (page) to the context of your node app.
If you want to work on the original array of elements, you can execute JavaScript on the context of the page inside the page.evaluate handler.

The problem with executing JS inside the page.evaluate() is that console.log() doesn't output anything. Assuming I want 50 (out of about 200) properties, do I have to list every property I want in the map() (twice)? Surely there's a better way?

You can have a page.on('console', onConsole) so you can see the messages in your async function onConsole(message) { console.log ('[PAGE] ' + message.text()) }

Sorry for being such a pain! Thinking about it some more, it might actually be desirable not to get the browser's console output in Node's console. There could be lots of JS errors on third-party websites.

Also, there's no need to list the properties twice, you can use an array with the properties names

@DannyBeckett What are you doing that would require you to access 50 different properties on an object? It sound like you'd just want to serialise the elements (e.g. via .outerHTML) and send that data back to node.

@Bergi I probably shouldn't have confused things by mentioning 50, it was just an arbitrary number.

Access the properties inside the evaluate function, in the code that's running in the page, and send back only the results of your function back to the driver process. In your particular example, you'll want to simplify to
(await page.evaluate(() =>
   Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a'), a => `<a href="${a.href}">${a.innerText.trim()}</a>`)
)).forEach(console.log);


I really like the elegant simplicity of this solution, thank you!
